# issue with using pointer to member function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, operator-precedence, pointer-to-member

This line of code has been giving me a load of trouble:

```
while(!list.add(list.*get().children()));
```

It is out of context, but Im simply trying to use the class member function pointer get(). Can someone please offer constructive feedback?

```
struct State
{
    State *children();
};
class List
{
    State *getBFS();
    State *getDFS();
    State *getUCS();
    State *getGS();
    State *getAStar();
public:
    State *(List::*get)();
    bool add(State *state);
    List(short type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
        case 0: get = &List::getBFS;
            break;
        case 1: get = &List::getDFS;
            break;
        case 2: get = &List::getUCS;
            break;
        case 3: get = &List::getGS;
            break;
        default: get = &List::getAStar;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    List list(0);
    while(!list.add((list.*get()).children()));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of `operator()` is higher than [`operator.*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_pointer-to-member_access_operators), so you should change

```
list.*get()
```

to

```
(list.*get)()
```

**EDIT**

What you want should be

```
while(!list.add(((list.* list.get)())->children()));
//                       ~~~~~       ~~
```

Note (1) `get` is a member of `List`; (2) the return type of `get` is a pointer (i.e. `State*`), so you should use `->` instead of `.`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I tried that but it still says 'identifier "get" is undefined'. Here is where I declared the pointer: State *(List::*get)();

Comment: @tayfun2150 More context is required. Better to provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution! I dont understand why it's (list.*list.get)() instead of (list.*get)(), but it seems to work

Comment: @tayfun2150 Because `get` is a member, so you should use it as `list.get`, just as you wrote `list.add`.